# pixel values of image are changed without modification in opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I tried to detect edges of an image. For that, I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
img = cv2.imread('download.jpg',0)
img1 = img
k = img.shape
i=1
x=k[0]
y=k[1]
print x,y
while(i<(x-2)):
    j=1
    while(j<(y-2)):
        a = (int(img[i,j+1])-int(img[i,j]))
        b = (int(img[i+1,j])-int(img[i,j]))
        c = (a**2) + (b**2)
        img1[i,j] = math.sqrt(c)
        #img1[i,j] = a
        j+=1
    i+=1
i=1
print "img"
print img
print "img1"
print img1
print i,j
cv2.imshow("image1",img1)
cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

No where in the code img is modified. Yet, at the end of the code, the pixel values of img are changed(which are same as img1). Can anybody explain me what Iam missing?

Comment: perform deep copy.. i.e. img1=img.clone(); instead of assignment.

Comment: Is not the key of the question, but your "edge detection" is simply the gradient magnitude. You can compute that faster using numpy as: `dy, dx = np.gradient(img); magnitude = np.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2))`.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is, assignment statements in Python do not copy objects,
after you did `img1 = img`, `img` and `img1` still point to the same Image object, you need to make a copy if you need to mutate the objects independently

You can also simply instantiate two Image objects

```
img = cv2.imread('download.jpg', 0)
img1 = cv2.imread('download.jpg', 0)
```

Otherwise you'll need to copy the python object `img`, e.g. using https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html